# Passing parameter from one viewmodel to another one using messenger

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

Whenever I want to open a new window from a View model, normally I am using messenger . 
But now I want to open a new window from a view model and  pass an object  from calling  view model to called  view model . How can I implement this?
In my viewmodelbase class currently I am having following methods.

```
public void SendNotificationMessage(string notification)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage(notification));
        }

        public void SendNotificationMessageAction(string notification, Action<object> callback)
        {
            var message = new NotificationMessageAction<object>(notification, callback);
            Messenger.Default.Send(message);
        }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax would look something like this:

```
//Subscribe
Messenger.Default.Register<OpewNewWindowMessage>(OpenNewWindowMethod);

// Broadcast
var message = new OpewNewWindowMessage();
message.ViewModel = this;
Messenger.Default.Send<OpewNewWindowMessage>(message);

// Subscribed method would look like this
void OpenNewWindowMethod(OpewNewWindowMessage e)
{
    // e.ViewModel would contain your ViewModel object
}
```

In the above example, you would create a new class called `OpewNewWindowMessage` and give it a property of `ViewModel`, then you would populate that value before broadcasting the message.

The `OpenNewWindowMethod()` would receive the message, and could access `OpewNewWindowMessage.ViewModel` to access the ViewModel property

Technically you don't need to create a message object if you're only passing around one property, however I usually find it makes the code easier to read and maintain if you create a message object instead of using a generic `<object>` like you have in your code.